# How does my computer know to assign a certain image to .doc files?

Tags: ms-word, operating-system

Is the icon file for .doc and .docx built-in to Windows, Mac, and Linux because it's so common? Or would the OS only know to associate that extension with the icon image IF Microsoft word/office was installed, which gave the image file to the OS and instructed it to make the association?

I didn't know how to search for this. I also didn't know whether to ask on Superuser, SO, or Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, when an application is installed, it registers with the OS what file extension it has for the files. So when you install Office or MS Word, it will tell the OS that it's files can be `.doc` or `.docx` and what icon to use for those. Then when any files that have that extension are shown, it will open up in that program. It stores the info in the registry.

If you try to open a `.docx` file that is not registered, meaning Office not installed, it will ask you to choose a program to launch it with, because it doesn't recognize the file.
You can also manually associate files as well to a specific program if it is not registered.

Most of the time, the associations are done when the said application is installed.

Some operating systems such as Mac and Linux can associate files with their mime type e.g. `text/plain`. That way it would know to use a text editor to open the file.

You can read a little more detail here about file associations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_association

Answer (score 1):

In windows vista/7, go to your control panel, and search for 'assoc'. Under folder options it has a option labeled 'change the file type associated with a file extension'. This will give you a list of all of the files extension (what comes after the '.') and what program/icon they use.

Most programs create these extensions when they are installed. Some very common formats, like .html, will have association made on any modern system.

Files also get associated when you tell the system which program to use to open a type of file. The icon that type of file uses is usually just the icon associated with the program in that case.

Hope that answers your question.